# Splitting String in two parts in Python

Tags: python, split-function

I have a column with the values like these

```
EUR, London , Germany
USD , New York , Boston, Canada
INR , Delhi, Mumbai
```

I am trying to extract the portion after the first ',' into another column, something like this

```
Desired output:
    London , Germany
    New York , Boston, Canada
    Delhi, Mumbai
```

but, when I use Events['Col2'] = Events['OriginalColumn'].str.split(',').str[1:7], I get the desired however its in array, I dont the result to be come in square brackets and in quotes. Below is what I get

```
[' London','Germany']
[' New York','Boston','Canada']
['Delhi', 'Mumbai']
```

Is there a way in which we can avoid the square brackets and the quotes. thanks in advance.

Comment: `.join()` will join lists of strings back into a single string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the column you are referring to is a column in a pandas DataFrame. In that case you can use the parameter `n` of `pandas.Series.str.split` to limit the number of splits to one, e.g.

```
Events['Col2'] = Events['OriginalColumn'].str.split(',', n=1).str[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming x is what you started your question with:

```
for i in x:
    row=i.split(',')[1:]
    print(' '.join([(row[k]) for k in range(len(row))]))
```